# Python-twitter でエラー AttributeError: 'Api' object has no attribute '_Api__auth'

Tags: python, api, twitter

現在、SNS分析のためにPythonでPython-twitterを使おうと考えています。oauth2,httplib2,simplejsonをそれぞれインストールし、Python‐twitterのインストールまでは行うことができました。（それぞれimportで確認済み）
しかし以下のようなエラーが出てしました。

Pythonなどのプログラミング言語も全て今年の春から学習し始めた初心者です。
googleや本を読みながらなんとかここまで来ましたが先に進めません。どうぞよろしくお願いします。

**エラー内容**

※ユーザー名は伏字にしてあります

```
    >>> api = twitter.Api()
    >>> statuses = api.GetUser('*********')

   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File `"<pyshell#10>",` line 1, in <module>
    statuses = api.GetUser('********')
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twitter\api.py", line 1847, in GetUser
    if not self.__auth:
AttributeError: 'Api' object has no attribute '_Api__auth'
```

**環境**
python2.7.8
httplib2-0.9.2
oauthlib-1.0.3
simplejson-3.8.0
python-twitter-2.2

Comment: ['Api' object has no attribute '_Api__auth'](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/issues/119#issuecomment-119081983)

Answer (score 2):

Githubに同じ質問がありました。
https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/issues/119

`twitter.Api()`に認証用の4つの引数を与え、以下の形にすれば動くと思います。

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
                  consumer_secret='consumer_secret',
                  access_token_key='access_token',
                  access_token_secret='access_token_secret')
```

token等の取得方法はドキュメントのAPIの項にあります。
https://github.com/bear/python-twitter#api

日本語だと、少し古いですが例えば以下のブログ記事に説明がありました。
[Twitterアプリケーションの作成（Consumer key、Consumer secret、Access token、Access token secretの確認方法）](http://website-planner.com/twitter%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%EF%BC%88consumer-key%E3%80%81consumer-secret%E3%80%81access-token%E3%80%81access-token-secret/)